# Multiple Choose From Lists on User Form

Tags: vb.net, sapb1

I have a custom user form with a working Choose From List which selects CardName from the list of Business Partners and displays in an edit text.

Is it possible to add a second Choose From List to a separate edit text to Choose from the OITM Item Master Table?

The first Clf will only work when the form has the ObjectType Property set to 2 (Business Partners), Does this suggest that it is not possible to have a second cfl for another table on the Form?

When i Remove the property i receive this error:
[image]

Is there any way around this?

[image]

Comment: Please DO NOT post code as an image. Always post code as text, formatted as code. You can edit your question  to comply.

Comment: The image is of the error code, as i stated. You can edit your comment if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a missing  `DBDataSources.Add("OITM")`

For each Choose From List that is required on the form, the relevant SAP table must be added as a dbDatasource

The complete code for adding multiple Choose From Lists from different object types:

```
 Dim oForm As SAPbouiCOM.Form = Application.SBO_Application.Forms.Item(Me.UIAPIRawForm.UniqueID)

        oForm.DataSources.UserDataSources.Add("udsBpName", SAPbouiCOM.BoDataType.dt_SHORT_TEXT)

        Dim oCFLs As SAPbouiCOM.ChooseFromListCollection = oForm.ChooseFromLists
        Dim oCons As SAPbouiCOM.Conditions
        Dim oCon As SAPbouiCOM.Condition
        Dim oCFL As SAPbouiCOM.ChooseFromList
        Dim oCFLCreationParams As SAPbouiCOM.ChooseFromListCreationParams
        oCFLCreationParams = CType(Application.SBO_Application.CreateObject(SAPbouiCOM.BoCreatableObjectType.cot_ChooseFromListCreationParams), SAPbouiCOM.ChooseFromListCreationParams)
        oCFLCreationParams.MultiSelection = False
        oCFLCreationParams.ObjectType = "2"
        oCFLCreationParams.UniqueID = "CFL_Name"
        oCFL = oCFLs.Add(oCFLCreationParams)
        oCons = oCFL.GetConditions()
        oCon = oCons.Add()
        oCon.Alias = "CardType"
        oCon.Operation = SAPbouiCOM.BoConditionOperation.co_EQUAL
        oCon.CondVal = "C"
        oCFL.SetConditions(oCons)

        etBpName.DataBind.SetBound(True, "OCRD", "CardName")
        etBpName.ChooseFromListUID = "CFL_Name"
        etBpName.ChooseFromListAlias = "CardName"


        ' This Item Master dbDatasource Needs to be added to the form 
        ' Before the Cfl with matching object type (in this case 4) is added 
        oForm.DataSources.DBDataSources.Add("OITM")

        Dim oCFLs2 As SAPbouiCOM.ChooseFromListCollection = oForm.ChooseFromLists
        Dim oCons2 As SAPbouiCOM.Conditions
        Dim oCon2 As SAPbouiCOM.Condition
        Dim oCFL2 As SAPbouiCOM.ChooseFromList
        Dim oCFLCreationParams2 As SAPbouiCOM.ChooseFromListCreationParams
        oCFLCreationParams2 = CType(Application.SBO_Application.CreateObject(SAPbouiCOM.BoCreatableObjectType.cot_ChooseFromListCreationParams), SAPbouiCOM.ChooseFromListCreationParams)
        oCFLCreationParams2.MultiSelection = False
        oCFLCreationParams2.ObjectType = "4"
        oCFLCreationParams2.UniqueID = "CFL1"
        oCFL2 = oCFLs2.Add(oCFLCreationParams2)
        oCons2 = oCFL2.GetConditions()
        oCon2 = oCons2.Add()
        oCon2.Alias = "Validfor"
        oCon2.Operation = SAPbouiCOM.BoConditionOperation.co_EQUAL
        oCon2.CondVal = "Y"
        oCFL2.SetConditions(oCons2)

        EditText0.DataBind.SetBound(True, "OITM", "ItemCode")
        EditText0.ChooseFromListUID = "CFL1"
        EditText0.ChooseFromListAlias = "ItemCode"
```